# Sort/GroupBy files pre-uploaded using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, group-by, angular-file-upload

I want to group my files before to upload them by extension(The extension can not be defined in the mime type attribute defined by the upload infos. So I used **groupBy** defined by angular-filter and instead to put an attribute('file.name' for example) to the filter Im using a function to get the extension.
So I want my pre-loaded files appears like this:

- **Extension1**:

file3.Extension1

file1.Extension1

- **Extension2**:

file4.Extension2

file2.Extension2

This is my [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/huhjo9jm/51/)

Also my code:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="f in files | groupBy: fileExtension" style="font:smaller">
        {{f.name}}
    </li>
</ul>

$scope.fileExtension = function(file) {
    return file.name.split('.').pop();
};
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would transform your list of file names into a list of file groups inside of an ngController or service. Binding to this transformed collection becomes trivial in the view.

```
$scope.groups = groupByExt(filenames);

function groupByExt(filenames) {
    var extensions = [];
    var groups = [];
    angular.forEach(filenames, function(item) {
        var extension = item.substring(item.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
        if (!extensions[extension]) {
            var group = { name: extension, files: [] };
            extensions[extension] = group;
            groups.push(group);

            group.files.push({ name: item });
        }
        else {
            var group = extensions[extension];
            group.files.push({ name: item});
        }
    });
    return groups;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="group in groups">
        {{ group.name }}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="file in group.files">
                {{ file.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9gg7t7gn/)

You can also set up $watchers so that when the original filenames list changes, it updates the file groups:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('filenames', function(newVal, oldVal)    {
  if(newVal !== oldVal) {
      $scope.groups = groupByExt(newVal);
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9gg7t7gn/2/)

I would avoid filters because filters should not change the references of the underlying items (infinite digest issue)

Comment: Could you explain more or give me an example?